# Is this hadith aunthentic? "...so seek treatment (of illness) but do not treat (illness) with anything that is haraam."

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity

It was narrated that Abu’d-Darda’ said: The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said:

> “Allah has sent down the disease and the remedy, and He has created a
>   remedy for every disease, so seek treatment (of illness) but do not
>   treat (illness) with anything that is haraam.”

Answer (score 2):

This hadith is a weak Hadith from Sunan Abi Dawud, as classified by Al-Albani, [according to sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/29/20).

**Edit:** As pointed by **@goldPseudo** and **@American Muslim** (in the comments), some sources marked this hadith as authentic. So, I did a little bit of research, and found the following sahih hadith:

> Narrated Tariq ibn Suwayd or Suwayd ibn Tariq:
>   Wa'il said: Tariq ibn Suwayd or Suwayd ibn Tariq asked the Prophet (ﷺ) about wine, but he forbade it. He again asked him, but he forbade him. He said to him: Prophet of Allah, it is a medicine. The Prophet (ﷺ) said: No it is a disease.
>
> [Abu Dawud [29:19]](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/29/19)

Since prophet Muhammad (pbuh) forbade alcohol even for medicinal purposes, it makes sense to say that **all** haram things are forbidden for medicinal purposes. As a result, the haith posted by OP is **authentic** since many sources marked it as authentic.

Comment: Huh. According to http://islamqa.info/en/170208, Al-Albani classified the same hadith as *sahih*. Your answer probably needs more work to establish which claim is actually more credible.

Comment: @goldPseudo It was first classified by the Albani as weak, then in his final works `السلسلة الصحيحة` #1633 he reverted it to Hadith sahih.

Comment: @both of you, thanks for pointing that out. I always considered sunnah.com to be correct, so this came out as a big surprise to me. Anyways, I updated my answer with a different view.

Comment: dear friend
i have a question then. many of us use cough medicine etc... it contains a little bit of alcohol but that is purely for treatement purposes.. another hadith says that " Actions are judged by intentions" so if our intentions are clean nd we use the medicine containing alcohol purely for treatement purposes than whats wrong with that.??

Comment: I don't have a proof/evidence but I have read somewhere that: Use whatever you want as the medicine, but the haram will not benefit you but for your own satisfaction, you can go ahead and use it as medicine, you're allowed to do so.